# Ask user to enter Lines of text.?

Tags: c++

Let's say in my (console) program I ask the user to enter their Biography. (or any kind of text resulting in a couple of lines).

This would be my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string bio;
    cout << "Please Enter Your Bio\n";
    cin >> bio;
}
```

Problems:

1. I don't know if a string can hold that much text.
2. I know cin will stop taking input after the user enters a "space" between words,so what are the options to store input as a whole? I've read getline can be used but I'm not sure how to.
3. If the user wants to start another paragraph, the moment the user hits "enter" it will take it as if he's done writing and the code will proceed.
   Therefore making it impossible for the user to write an actual Biography.

Comment: These are three completely separate questions. It is good practice here to ask only one question per question. As a matter of fact, the first one (can a string hold that much text?) is a really good question. Still, please look if it has already been answered, by using the search function.

Comment: Those are questions regarding the same issue, for solving an ultimate common goal. So they work as context to each other imo.

Answer (score 2):

Short of writing or linking to a text editor, this isn't going to be a very nice program to use.  For example, if the user makes a mistake on a line that's already entered, there is no way to go back and edit it.

However, just to entertain the idea, this kind of thing *is* done in certain cases (e.g. the unix program `mail`), and usually the expectation is that existing input will be piped into the program rather than being interactive with a user.

You don't have to worry about the string being large enough.  It can hold a lot.  You just need to decide whether to use some delimiter to end the input, or end of stream.  Both are valid.

- Option 1: Terminate input only on end of stream:

  ```
  std::string bio, line;
  while( std::getline( std::cin, line ) ) bio += line;
  ```
- Option 2: Terminate input on end of stream or delimiter (in this case a single period `.` on a line by itself, but it could be anything, including empty string to stop input on the first empty line):

  ```
  std::string bio, line;
  while( std::getline( std::cin, line ) && line != "." ) bio += line;
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Use getline with your input stream (cin) and your string object (bio)

```
geline(cin, bio);
```

You can get the maximum possible size of a string object via it's max_size() method.

And you can specify the "end" character of the getline funcion, for example, you can use the "end of file" character '\0'

```
getline(cin, bio, '\0');
```

The user can write multiple lines of text, then press CTRL+D to end it's input

Comment: That's basically correct. But what makes the difference? Explain more in your answer please.